# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access while updating ListPicker in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm building simple WP8 application. I'm trying to update a `ListPicker` control with a collection that is a member of another class. This class obtains this data with an asynchronous call. When the response is received that triggers an event on the MainPage that updates the `ListPicker`.

```
    public void coinUtil_ReceivedPriceEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateListPicker();
    }

    public void PopulateListPicker()
    {

        try
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in coinUtil.cointPriceList)
            {

                listPickerCurrencies.Items.Add(item.Key);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread
>   access. at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread() at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp) at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.get_Items() at
>   BitCoinTail.MainPage.PopulateListPicker()

Strangely when I try to access another member of this class with a simple string it works fine. I was developing a little bit in WP7 but don't recall ever getting this exception. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to use a Dispatcher to ensure that the UI is updated on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a dispatcher to marshal a call to the proper thread - see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368983/Invoking-through-the-Dispatcher-on-Windows-Phone-a

Comment: I run into such solution while I was googling but I don't understand where this comes from. How is it possible that I can access **String** but I can't access **List** object?

Comment: I guess it would depend if it caused a UI update... not 100% sure though

Comment: Well it did but not directly. The fact that the the list in `SomeClass` was populated with values triggered event handler on the `MainPage`. I'll try to implement Dispatcher and see what happens.