# Shake Gesture Library in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, accelerometer, dispatcher

I am trying to design a Game which generates **Random Numbers** on **Shaking the phone**. I am using **Shake Gesture Library** , Refer link below:

[Link: Shaking-up-your-WP7](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Shaking-up-your-WP7-app-is-easy-to-do-with-the-Shake-Gesture-Library)

I change the default sample code from:

```
    private void Instance_ShakeGesture(object sender, ShakeGestureEventArgs e)
{
    _lastUpdateTime.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        () =>
        {
            _lastUpdateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            CurrentShakeType = e.ShakeType;
        });
}
```

TO:

```
  private void Instance_ShakeGesture(object sender, ShakeGestureEventArgs e)
{
              PlayButton_Click(null, null); 

}
```

PlayButton_Click() is my method which contains  rest statements to generate random numbers.

I shake my phone, but it is showing me error after going into first statement of PlayButton_Click() :

**An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: Looks like a cross thread issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100230/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-invalid-cross-thread-access-while-updating-l

Comment: Code looks fine. VS allows you to break execution on any exception thrown, check which exact line throws it. It's an option you can enable in Debugger -> Exceptions.

Comment: I just want to Run the PlayButton_Click() method on Shake detection.   

PlaysCount++;
 NumPlays.Text = PlaysCount.ToString(); 

Second statement is giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that PlayButton_Click is accessing UI components, the call to Instance_ShakeGesture comes through on a non-UI thread, you can't access UI components on any thread other than the main UI thread. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is used to put the request on the UI thread.  You need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to call your PlayButton_Click

```
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        () =>
        {
            PlayButton_Click(null, null); 
        });
```

Comment: _lastUpdateTime is a TextBlock is sample code which changes text on SHAKE. But I have no such textblock. I just want to Run the PlayButton_Click() method on Shake detection.

Comment: There are many ways of accessing the Dispatcher.  I've updated the answer to put the absolute sure fire way of calling it

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Dispatcher' and no extension method 'Dispatcher' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  WPF and WP8 differences. Try the code in the edit

Comment: Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. C:\Users\Atif\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LuckyMe\LuckyMe\MainPage.xaml.cs 124 86 LuckyMe

Comment: No worries.  Sorry for the multiple edits.  Not done WP8 development.  Best way to thank me would be to mark it as the answer to give me credit